# ML muliplication

Tags: sml, ml

Using SML, I have to create a recursive function to do the following

```
fun mult ([a,b,c]) - multiply a*b c times

example:  mult ([2,3,5]) -> [2, 6, 18, 54, 162, 486]
```

Update:  I have the following

```
fun mult (a, b) = a*b;

fun multin ([a, b, c]) = if c=0 then nil
                     else mult(a, b) :: multin ([mult(a,b), b, c-1]);

multin ([2, 3, 5]);
```

results in:   val it = [6,18,54,162,486] : int list

I need the first element to be 2 in this case. If I make the base case if c=0 then [a], then it just repeats whatever the last element was; in this case it was repeating 486.

Comment: hi, welcome to StackOverflow! if you don't know where to start, start googling about recursive.. after you tried and face a problem, please try to ask again on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you count up since the list is going up? something like

```
fun mult ([a,b,k],c) = a*b^k::mult([a,b,k+1],c)

mult([a,b,0],c)
```

Not sure what the operator for power is ^ but you get the idea.

Then terminate your loop when k increments reaches c.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a helper unless you require the function to be tail recursive.

The first thing to observe is that if `c` is zero, the answer is `[a]`. That's the base case of your recursion. Otherwise, you need to construct a list that is `a` consed onto the rest of the answer, which you can obtain with a recursive call.

That should be enough of a hint to get started.

Comment: Careful! If `c` is `0`, the answer is the singleton list `[a]`.

Comment: @Michael: if `c` is zero, you want a list `[a]`, not `nil`. (I've changed `a * b` to `a`, too, after taking Eduardo's suggestion into account.)